# Pytorch Downloading Data with DDP Torchrun

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to understand how DDP works with Pytorch torchrun (which I am running with AWS Sagemaker), specifically as it pertains to the downloading of training data.

I am using a single instance with multiple GPUs. It seems that I need to download the training data on each process  - which is a Pandas DF - and then create a dataset and data loader. Is this the case? So on each value of local_rank, the data needs to be downloaded and a data set and loader created? Does this load the data on each GPU? so you need to fit the data on the GPU memory??